# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "open": error=2, No such file or directory in MAC (dmg)

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error, processbuilder

We have a java swing application which contains documents module when double-clicking any of the document which is opening in my IDE(Eclipse). Every time when I am executing my code which is working fine in the codebase but Unable to view a document in Java 11 dmg and it is working fine in Java 8, dmg as well in codebase also working good in the EXE.
This is the error I am getting every time while trying to open a document during runtime
**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "open": error=2, No such file or directory**
This is my code,

```
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("open", documentLocation);
ps.start();
```

Have tried,

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "sudo chmod 755"+ " "+documentLocation+"");
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("open","-n", documentLocation);
ps.start();
```

another attempt,

```
File file = new File(documentLocation);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open", file.getAbsolutePath()});
```

This is working file in codebase in MAC, How do I fix this on dmg(Runtime execution)
What changes need to be done in my code.

Comment: Does this article on **Unix & Linux Stack Exchange** answer your question? [`open` command to open a file in an application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253376)

Comment: Or maybe this article on **Super User**? [Linux equivalent command for “open” command on Mac/Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/38984/880842)

Comment: I think you are looking for class [java.awt.Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html). By the way, what is ___dmg___ ?